# What function is func here? Where did it come from?

Tags: python, function

This is my code:

```
def testit(func, *nkwargs, **kwargs):
     try:
        retval = func(*nkwargs, **kwargs)
        result = (True, retval)
     except Exception, diag:
        result = (False, str(diag))
     return result

def test():
     funcs = (int, long, float)
     vals = (1234, 12.34, '1234', '12.34')

     for eachFunc in funcs:
        print '-' * 20
        for eachVal in vals:
            retval = testit(eachFunc, eachVal)
            if retval[0]:
               print '%s(%s) =' % \
                     (eachFunc.__name__, `eachVal`), retval[1]
            else:
               print '%s(%s) = FAILED:' % \
                     (eachFunc.__name__, `eachVal`), retval[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

What is the function of the `func` in the third line. I think it is a variable. How did it become a function name?

Comment: In python, functions are first-class citizens, this means you can use them as regular variables and pass them to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python functions are first-class objects. This means you can assign such an object to a variable and pass it to another function. The very act of executing a `def functionname(): ...` statement assigns such an object to a name (`functionname` here):

```
>>> def foo(): return 42
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x107e9f0d0>
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar
<function foo at 0x107e9f0d0>
>>> bar()
42
```

So the expression

```
funcs = (int, long, float)
```

takes 3 built-in functions and puts those into a tuple. `funcs[0]('10')` would return the integer object `10`, because `funcs[0]` is another reference to the `int()` function, so `funcs[0]('10')` would give you the exact same outcome as `int('10')`.

Those function objects are passed to the `testit()` function in a loop with:

```
 for eachFunc in funcs:
    print '-' * 20
    for eachVal in vals:
        retval = testit(eachFunc, eachVal)
```

So `eachFunc` is bound to the function objects that the `funcs` tuple references, one by one.

`testit()` takes that function object as the `func` parameter, then calls it:

```
def testit(func, *nkwargs, **kwargs):
     try:
        retval = func(*nkwargs, **kwargs)
```

so this calls `int()`, `long()` and `float()` on various test values, from the `values` tuple.